# Does unity transform world to local considering rotation

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics-engine

I want to implement oriented collision in unity as a test, and for convenience I just wanted to know if local space is also based on rotation. I wanted to check at least two objects against each other while also being accurate to their rotation. Is it true?

Comment: This sounds like a question you can answer by testing it. Have you seen any evidence that suggests rotation is NOT considered in these transformations?